# Element is properly getting stickied over other elements

Tags: html, css

Here is a codesandbox of what I have: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-surf-5vyy2

The pink square is stickied the way I want to but now I need to add a container so that the content doesnt stretch through the whole page.

THis is what the html looks like now:

```
<body>
    <div style="height:200vh;background-color:blue">
        <div style="width:50%;height:100vh;float:left;background-color:red"></div>
        <div style="width:50%;height:50vh;float:right;background-color:pink;position:sticky;top:0">
          <h1>I'm Sticky!</h1>
        </div>
      <div style="width:100%;height:100vh;float:left;background-color:green">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>I'm full width</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100vw;height:75vh;background-color:white">
      <h2>No sticky here</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
```

If I were to add:

```
<body>
    <div style="height:200vh;background-color:blue">
        <div class='container'> <--------------------------THIS
           <div style="width:50%;height:100vh;float:left;background-color:red"></div>
           <div style="width:50%;height:50vh;float:right;background-color:pink;position:sticky;top:0">
             <h1>I'm Sticky!</h1>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="width:100%;height:100vh;float:left;background-color:green">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>I'm full width</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100vw;height:75vh;background-color:white">
      <h2>No sticky here</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
```

It breaks the sticky. Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `container` div has no height. please add that rule to 100% in your css:

```
.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```